# $L^\infty(0,1)$ as $C(K)$

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces

For any $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$, the space $L^\infty(\mu)$ is isometric (even as a Banach algebra) to the space $C(K)$ of continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space $K$. For example, $\ell^\infty=L^\infty({\bf N})=C(\beta {\bf N})$.

Is there some canonical (or at least fairly explicit) $K$ for which $L^\infty(0,1)$ (with Lebesgue measure) is isometric to $C(K)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question have been already [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99091/spectrum-of-l-inftyx-mu) on MO. For a more detailed discussion of the spectrum of arbitrary $L_\infty$-space see page 28 in [Second duals of measure algebras. H. G. Dales, A. T.-M. Lau](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmt6hgd/preprints/Dissertatmeasurealgebrafinal.pdf)

Comment: Of course! It is a commutative, unital $C^*$-algebra. The proof I've seen of the general fact was more general and I missed the obvious explanation. "The maximal spectrum" is quite sufficiently explicit and canonical for me. Thanks!

Comment: Another explicit $K$ is the Stone space of the Lebesgue measure algebra (on $[0,1]$).

Comment: implicitly everything we mention here as $K$ is essentially implicit because of ultrafilters hidden somewhere inside

Comment: The same can be said about $\beta {\bf N}$.